# Regex solution to ignore .com and .org or .net

Tags: python, regex

I have the following strings

```
str1="Google.com"
str2="yahoo.com"
str3="redcross.org"
```

My question is, what is the efficient Regex solution to ignore .com, .org or .net

expected output

```
Google
yahoo
redcross
```

Comment: Do you know about Regex101.com? You should not ignore .com there ;-)

Comment: try this ``re.sub("\\.(com|org|net)", "", "google.com")``

Comment: @Sushanth that did the trick, thanks

Comment: Either match `^\S+(?=\.[^\s.]+$)` or replace the match of `\.[^\s.]+$` with an empty string, though my simplistic `\S` should really be replaced by a character class containing permitted characters. [ref[(https://regex101.com/r/PoTkXp/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re # Standard regex module


# The ReGeX
regex = re.compile('([\\.a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(?=\\.[a-z]{3,5})')

# The document to extract websites (suffix excluded) from
doc = """
str1="Google.com"
str2="yahoo.com"
str3="redcross.org"
"""

# Find websites (without the suffix) like so:
found_websites = regex.findall(doc)

# Confirm by printing
print(found_websites)
```

Output:

```
['Google', 'yahoo', 'redcross']
```

Proof of functionaility: [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ffCC3e/5)

EDIT: I made a more information-rich website finder (not what you want, I think, but may deem useful) [here](https://regex101.com/r/alp5Kb/2)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well, I don't think he'll ever find websites that look like that. And if he does, then my regex still works. The thing is, I needed to match periods (dots) in order to get stuff like `maps.google.com` and the underscore is apparently an alphanumeric character.

Comment: I'll update it so instead of `\w`, I'll use `[a-zA-Z0-9.]`

Answer (score 0):

In python you can do this

```
import re
str_list = re.findall(r"\w*", string_input)
output = str_list[0]
```

Comment: Luckily I don't have it in my file. In my line of work, I don't think I will encounter maps.google.com. But thanks for bringing up this corner case.